# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined in functiom

Tags: javascript

**I start my first web devolper bootcamp and i did write the same code as the educator, however there is an error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" after adding this class to the function :**

```
.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 #DBEDF3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**the js code page :**

```
function makeSound(key) {
  switch(key){
    case "w":
    var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-2.mp3');
    audio.play();
  break;
    case "a":
    var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-1.mp3');
    audio.play();
  break;
    case "s":
    var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
    audio.play();
  break;

    case "d":
    var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
    audio.play();
  break;

  case "j":
  var audio = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
  audio.play();
  break;

  case "k":
  var audio = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
  audio.play();
  break;

  case "l":
  var audio = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
  audio.play();
  break;
  default:
  console.log(butnhtml);
}
}

// animetion


function animetion (curk){

var activeButton =document.querySelectorAll("."+curk);
activeButton.classlist.add("pressed ");
setTimeout(function(){
  activeButton.classlist.remove("pressed ");     }
    , 100);
}

// mouse

var n =document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length ;
for(var i =0 ; i<n ; i++){
document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function (){

var butnhtml= this.innerHTML;
makeSound(butnhtml);
animetion(butnhtml);
})
}
// keyboard
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
animetion(event.key);
  makeSound(event.key);
});
```

**the "add" in animation section isn't working but if i add the same class to h1 it will work and i'm using chrome as browser and atom ad codeeditor wish you can help me solve this proplem**

Comment: Try `classList` instead of `classlist`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `classList` instead of `classlist`.

Also, `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList. You have to iterate it through it and use `classList.add()` on each element.

```js
var activeButton = document.querySelectorAll("." + curk);

activeButton.forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.add("pressed");

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.classList.remove("pressed");
  }, 100);
}
```

If you only need to apply it to one element, you can use `document.querySelector()`, which returns the first match.

```js
var activeButton = document.querySelector("." + curk);
activeButton.classList.add("pressed");

setTimeout(function(){
  activeButton.classList.remove("pressed");
}, 100);
```